# no such method org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf SpringJPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jboss

So I have no idea whenever this started as my project seemed to work perfectly last week and this week throws this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:533)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:981)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:700)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:673)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-04-19 10:46:02 [main] Ontolobridge-dev ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
```

So I went through the POM dependency tree and removed all imports of jboss-logging as I saw on a few stack overflows from 5 years ago to last year. However jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar is still somehow imported. So I deleted the jar so its no longer in the class path and according to the POM is no longer in the dependency tree and yet every time I start the application it gets redownloaded. I cannot use a higher version as the older version is downloaded even if the newer version already exists.

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.miami.schurer</groupId>
    <artifactId>ontologbridge</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ontologbridge</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Mysql Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies --><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-logback</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Tried removing all `jboss-logging` as you can see in the pom[exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32913401/10524487)
Tried deleting the jar from the .m2 repository but it gets reloaded anyways
Tried doing the glassfish fix with glassfish-web.xml [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38439108/10524487)
Tried posting to github due to lack of answers in other threads but closed and told to come back here.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.jboss.logging.Logger, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/<user>/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar!/org/jboss/logging/Logger.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/<user>/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.jboss.logging.Logger
```

MVN Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< edu.miami.schurer:ontologbridge >-------------------
[INFO] Building ontologbridge 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ ontologbridge ---
[INFO] edu.miami.schurer:ontologbridge:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.5:runtime
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.34:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.34:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.34:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- it.ozimov:spring-boot-email-core:jar:0.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.lettuce:lettuce-core:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- it.ozimov:embedded-redis:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.owasp.encoder:encoder:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.sentry:sentry:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] \- io.sentry:sentry-logback:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.686 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-20T16:36:21-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I fix this.

Comment: Remove the excludes, remove the `org.jboss.logging` dependency and use `hibernate-validator` version 6. Version 7 isn't supported by Spring as that is an implementation of Jakarata Validation not Javax Validation. That `hibernate-validator` dependency is probably also the one pulling in the unsupported version.

Comment: Still same issue, dropped validator to 6.0.21.final and removed jakarta.xml.bind as well as the exclusions

Comment: You also need to remove the `jboss-logging` dependency. The version you have isn't compatible with the version of hibernate you are using, which is the cause for the error.

Comment: That is removed, same issue

Comment: Then you aren't telling the whole story (if I recall you already had another issue with those dependencies). Something is pulling in an incompatible `Jboss-logging` dependency. Check what pulls in what and figure out a way to pull in the proper version.

Comment: I have updated the pom in the question and added a dependency:tree which shows the only thing loading JBoss-Logging is hibernate-validator with a newer version. I have no idea what is importing the lower version

Comment: Use spring-boot-starter-validation instead of adding random versions op hibernate-validator. That way the versions will be managed by spring.

Comment: I have updated the dependency tree, the issue still occurs

Comment: I doubt it is the same error. You only added the dependencies. Please update the logging output as well. You also have 2 hibernate-validators in your dependency tree.

Comment: Everything is update, logging output, the pom, and the dependecny tree

Comment: How are you running this? You are building a War and the logging looks non standard. Did you accidentility include the jar in your run config?

Comment: I am running this with Intellij Generic spring boot profile they include

Comment: So I started looking through all the includes and found that at some point hibernate-validators was added to the project includes that the IDE manages. So every start it was redownloading hibernate-validators and its 3.1.3 jboss