# Hibernate 5.2.1 Glassfish 4.1.1 Project Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf

Tags: hibernate, maven, glassfish

I have created a project using JSF, hibernate, glassfish framework and MySQL

But when I try to store one user in my database, I get these errors :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:98)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at dao.PersistenceManager.getEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceManager.java:15)
at dao.GenericDao.create(GenericDao.java:18)
at Session.HelloMyBite.getWelcomeMessage(HelloMyBite.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:154)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

persistanceManager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="My-PU"
                  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>
        org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    </provider>

    <properties>
        <property
                name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property
                name="javax.persistence.jdbc.users"
                value="root" />
        <property
                name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                value="" />
        <property
                name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myjsfTest" />
        <property
                name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
                value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"    value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>4JVA</groupId>
<artifactId>4JVA</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

PersistenceManager class:

```
package dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Created by sya on 1/10/2017.
 */
public class PersistenceManager {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    // Lazy initialization
    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        if(emf == null){
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("My-PU");

        }
        return emf;
    }

    //Private constructor prevent instantiation
    private PersistenceManager(){}

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if(emf != null && emf.isOpen()) emf.close();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please add your `pom.xml` to the question. I've had the issue two months ago. It's a problem of logging framework versions

Comment: @JimHawkins I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate 5 + Glassfish 4.1.1: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813782/hibernate-5-glassfish-4-1-1-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-lo)

Comment: Have you tried this?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34814752/212224

Comment: You should also change your JBoss logging dependency to `provided` scope since it is already in GlassFish:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/767661c71af61b3eb8e8f854e88dbe074a440d5c/appserver/pom.xml#L150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the solution :

```
Problem :The version of glassfish 
     glassfish 4.1.1 has problem with the jdbc you can't create the jdbc in the control panel of glassfish 4.1.1

Solution : Use the glassfish 4.0.0
```