# I am creating an shopping cart and i get some error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I get such output error:

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'myDBAuthenticationService': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.AccountDAO
>   org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.authentication.MyDBAuthenticationService.accountDAO;
>   nested exception is 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDAO': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl.sessionFactory;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>       Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.config.ApplicationContextConfig:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>       org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is 
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

```
<!-- language: none -->



In MYDBAuthenticationService.java

    package org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.authentication;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.AccountDAO;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.entity.Account;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class MyDBAuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private AccountDAO accountDAO;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Account account = accountDAO.findAccount(username);
            System.out.println("Account= " + account);

            if (account == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " //
                        + username + " was not found in the database");
            }

            // EMPLOYEE,MANAGER,..
            String role = account.getUserRole();

            List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

            // ROLE_EMPLOYEE, ROLE_MANAGER
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role);

            grantList.add(authority);

            boolean enabled = account.isActive();
            boolean accountNonExpired = true;
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
            boolean accountNonLocked = true;

            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(account.getUserName(), //
                    account.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, //
                    credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, grantList);

            return userDetails;
        }

    }

    In applicationcontextconfig.java
    package org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.config;

    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.AccountDAO;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.OrderDAO;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.ProductDAO;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.impl.OrderDAOImpl;
    import org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.dao.impl.ProductDAOImpl;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.*")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    // Load to Environment.
    @PropertySource("classpath:ds-hibernate-cfg.properties")
    public class ApplicationContextConfig {

        // The Environment class serves as the property holder
        // and stores all the properties loaded by the @PropertySource
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
            ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            // Load property in message/validator.properties
            rb.setBasenames(new String[] { "messages/validator" });
            return rb;
        }

        @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
        public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolver;
        }

        // Config for Upload.
        @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
        public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
            CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();

            // Set Max Size...
            // commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(...);

            return commonsMultipartResolver;
        }

        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

            // See: ds-hibernate-cfg.properties
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("ds.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password"));

            System.out.println("## getDataSource: " + dataSource);

            return dataSource;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            // See: ds-hibernate-cfg.properties
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
            properties.put("current_session_context_class", env.getProperty("current_session_context_class"));


            LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

            // Package contain entity classes
            factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.o7planning.springmvcshoppingcart.entity" });
            factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            //
            SessionFactory sf = factoryBean.getObject();
            System.out.println("## getSessionFactory: " + sf);
            return sf;
        }

        @Autowired
        @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
        public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

            return transactionManager;
        }

        @Bean(name = "accountDAO")
        public AccountDAO getApplicantDAO() {
            return new AccountDAOImpl();
        }

        @Bean(name = "productDAO")
        public ProductDAO getProductDAO() {
            return new ProductDAOImpl();
        }

        @Bean(name = "orderDAO")
        public OrderDAO getOrderDAO() {
            return new OrderDAOImpl();
        }

        @Bean(name = "accountDAO")
        public AccountDAO getAccountDAO()  {
            return new AccountDAOImpl();
        }

    }

    In pom.xml

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.o7planning</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringMVCAnnotationShoppingCart</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <name>SpringMVCAnnotationShoppingCart Maven Webapp</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


        <properties>
            <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        </properties>

        <repositories>
            <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
            <repository>
                <id>codelds</id>
                <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet API -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- JSP API -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

           <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
           <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
               <version>1.3.1</version>
           </dependency>        

            <!-- Spring dependencies -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->

            <!-- Hibernate -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.34</version>
            </dependency>

              <!-- Email validator,... -->
            <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>


        <build>
            <finalName>SpringMVCAnnotationShoppingCart</finalName>

        </build>


    </project>
```

Comment: it looks like hibernate spring version mismatch

Comment: how can i chaneg it where is the error barath plzz help

Comment: share the pom.xml

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547015/hibernate-5-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-debugf

Comment: plz look a my pom.xml if there is some error i am just begginer of spring and these code are copied by me to learn it but it didnot run

Comment: There are some conflic with Hibernate 5. Please using Hibernate 4. Remove Hibernate 5.1.0.Final in pom.xml.

Comment: @searching9x i have done the same but i get the same error "

Comment: has it fully runned on your computer??

Comment: You wrong code ApplicationContextConfig.java : import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;  ==> Change package hibernate5 ==> hibernate4.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you??

Comment: i m using mysql not oracle ... doesnt it run on mysql??

Comment: ok wait for some tym if it runs i will answer you :)

Comment: @searching9x  hlo bro the program is running but the css is not opening?

Answer (score 0):

Try, Commenting out below :

```
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->
```

Comment: i can provide u github link will you fix the error??? i have used netabeans