# NoSuchMethodError exception thrown when deploying WAR to WebLogic

Tags: war, weblogic12c, nosuchmethoderror, jboss-logging

We're trying to deploy a WAR to our client's Application Server with the following characteristics:

- S.O. Solaris 11.3 (SPARC)
- Java: 1.8.0_77-b03
- Weblogic  12.2.1
- Oracle Data Base 12c (12.1.0.2)

For development I work on a machine with:

- Windows 10
- Java 1.8.0.131
- Weblogic 12.2.1
- Oracle Data Base 12c (12.1.0.2)

When I deploy into my Weblogic I get no errors thrown, but when the deployment is done in the Solaris server the following error is thrown:

```
<c2e7203a-9ad2-488a-b846-e367f764c950-000005f4> <1496959017601> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149038> <Initiating task for qabogados : [Deployer:149026]deploy application qabogados on app_server_dev01..> 
####<Jun 8, 2017 4:57:22 PM CDT> <Info> <Health> <admin-dev> <AdminServer> <weblogic.GCMonitor> <<anonymous>> <> <c2e7203a-9ad2-488a-b846-e367f764c950-00000046> <1496959042458> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-310002> <25% of the total memory in the server is free.> 
####<Jun 8, 2017 4:57:33 PM CDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <admin-dev> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <c2e7203a-9ad2-488a-b846-e367f764c950-000005f9> <1496959053314> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "qabogados".> 
####<Jun 8, 2017 4:57:33 PM CDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <admin-dev> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <c2e7203a-9ad2-488a-b846-e367f764c950-000005f9> <1496959053314> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
                at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
                at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
                at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
                at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
                at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
                at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:149)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:771)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:486)
                at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1420)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1359)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1340)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1906)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
                at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
                at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
                at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
                at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
                at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
> 
####<Jun 8, 2017 4:57:33 PM CDT> <Error> <Console> <admin-dev> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <c2e7203a-9ad2-488a-b846-e367f764c950-000005f4> <1496959053356> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
                at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
                at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
                at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
                at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
                at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
                at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
                at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
                at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
                at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:149)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:771)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:486)
                at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1420)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1359)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1340)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1906)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
                at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
                at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
```

I looked around for this error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688361/1585340) answer so I checked my dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and found that *org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile (version managed from 3.3.0.Final)* was included as subdependency for:

- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile,
- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile,
- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile

I tried to exclude this JBoss library from my dependencies, which ended up looking like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But even when I excluded the library the error persists.

Is my understanding of the issue correct? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: The method org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf is only available in the jboss-logging version 3.3.0, if you have this dependency in your project also you have to check that your app server also have the same version

Comment: 1.Check for ALL "jboss-logging" sub-dependencies in the dependency hierarchy in pom.xml, and exclude all those dependencies. 2. Use the jboss-logging version which does have the method. As suggested on the link, 3.2.0.Final does.  <dependency>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>            
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>