# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on glassfish 4.1.2

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

I'm trying to port my application from glassfish 4.0 to 4.1.2.

On version 4.0 it works but on 4.1.2 i'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception on org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory, but i checked and everything should be ok all jars are in war's WEB-INF/lib.

```
[2017-07-04T08:14:02.152+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1499148842152] [levelValue: 900] [[
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cdsGasCallbackMessageDispatcher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/cdsgas-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySec' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySec' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cdsGasCallbackMessageDispatcher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/cdsgas-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySec' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySec' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Is it some weird bug in gf 4.1.2 or am i doing something wrong?

EDIT: It actually seems like it's some kind of spring issue, because when i take another project using commons logging and xmlsec but doesn't use spring it deploys and works.

Comment: Faced the same issue..there must be a dependency conflict..make sure you remove all jars/dependencies of the previous version ie 4.0

Comment: I tried to delete common-loggings jar from lib and now it's org.apache.xml.security.Init, here deleting didn't help

Comment: Hi @DavidS. how do you finally fix this issue?

Comment: Hi @lincetto, well i did not, we've just stayed on gf 4.0. I tried 4.1.1, 4.1.2 and even 5.0 and i faced same problem everywhere and for us it was better to just stay on 4.0 than solve this( in terms of time ). But i would still like to know how to fix this and move on to newer glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got you guys covered, let's try a few things.

First, which most likely won't work for you, try the things [here from stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551697/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory)
Specifically, the first three answers. I'm guessing, however, that you've already been there and done that. You're probably even pissed for me suggesting it. I only included it for anyone else who makes it here and needs the info.

So, since that most likely didn't work, there is probably, like Akshay mentioned, a dependency problem. I think your problem is Glassfish, not Spring. First, check your dependencies for problems.

If you're using maven, use dependency tree to see what conflicts and which library brings in what.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

The verbose gives you more info. Since you're looking for conflicts, go with:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep 'omitted for conflict'
```

Does you see omitted for conflicts on any loggers?

I've had a similar problem where a logger was clashing with the older logger from Glassfish. Glassfish had a much older version stored separately from the other dependencies that was screwing things up. *I had a problem with a jboss logger but it was the exact same error otherwise*. It was such a pain in the ass I wrote down how I fixed it and where the answer came from.

**The final solution** that helped me out was this top answer [from this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547015/hibernate-5-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-debugf/32278984) (You would have never found this so don't feel bad.)

> In glass fish This problem is caused by collision with dependencies of glassfish modules. If you check lib list in glassfishdir/modules you would see boss-logging.jar. You can delete it and replace with latest such as org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final. It worked for me.

Inside of my glassfish module (mine is located @ ->) C:\glassfish4\glassfish\modules ,there was an outdated version of the jboss-logger. I deleted that and replaced it with the jboss-logging 3.3.0 final jar and it WORKED!